# Magento2 : How Can I Update My Custom Fee While I Update Qty From Admin New Invoice Section

Tags: magento2, upgrade, invoice, qty

[image]

I have create one module to add custom fee to order product wise ,
for eg . **1 product = 10** , so **5 product = 50** , and custom fee is working fine in all section like `checkout`, `order`, `Invoice`

now my requirement is i need to update my custom fee when i update qty in admin new invoice section as per above screenshot.

I want if i update `qty to 0 for last 2` product than that `2 product custom fee` should not be add.

**If any one have idea than please tell me.**

Answer (score 0):

I struct on same issue.

I solved this , Create **sales_order_invoice_updateqty.xml** then copy content is in **sales_order_invoice_new.xml** and paste into **sales_order_invoice_updateqty.xml** save it.

After Flush a cache and check output.